# Loop using session

Tags: php

count value is changes on every refresh.

How to i store count value in variable and use in "for loop" over here `$x <= 10;`

```
<?php
  echo "<div class='p_list_heading'> Product Name </div>";
  echo "<div class='p_list_heading'> Product Price </div>";
  echo "<div class='p_list_heading'> Product Quantity </div>";
  echo count($_SESSION['product_name']);

   for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {

     if($_SESSION['product_name'][$x]!==""){

        echo "<div class=\"c_hold\">";
        echo "<div>".@$_SESSION['product_name'][$x]."</div>";
        echo "<div>".@$_SESSION['product_price'][$x]."Rs". "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
                                            }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please give me more information about what you want to do so I can help you

Answer (score 2):

Store in some variable `$y`

```
$y = count($_SESSION['product_name']);
for ($x = 0; $x <= $y; $x++) {
    if($_SESSION['product_name'][$x]!==""){
        echo "<div class=\"c_hold\">";
        echo "<div>".@$_SESSION['product_name'][$x]."</div>";
        echo "<div>".@$_SESSION['product_price'][$x]."Rs". "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Instead of storing in variable, you can also do:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= count($_SESSION['product_name']); $x++) {
    if($_SESSION['product_name'][$x]!==""){
        echo "<div class=\"c_hold\">";
        echo "<div>".@$_SESSION['product_name'][$x]."</div>";
        echo "<div>".@$_SESSION['product_price'][$x]."Rs". "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:

```
$count = count($_SESSION['product_name']);
echo $count;

for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++)
{
}
```